# Bash: wait for the child process spawned before exec'ing bash

Tags: bash, shell

Bash can use `wait` to wait for the processes it started directly. However, if the process forks a child, and then execs `bash` (that is, parent turns into `bash`), the newly exec'd Bash process cannot wait for the "inherited" child. Here is the minimal reproduction:

```bash
#/bin/bash
sleep inf &
pid=$!
exec bash -c "wait $pid;"'echo This shell is $$; sleep inf'
```

which gives this output:

```
$ bash test.sh
bash: wait: pid 53984 is not a child of this shell
This shell is 53983
```

The pstree, however, shows that the child pid is indeed the child of the shell:

```
$ pstree -p 53983
bash(53983)─┬─sleep(53984)
            └─sleep(53985)
```

It seems that Bash tracks the spawned processes internally, and consults this list rather than calling `waitpid(2)` directly (`zsh` has the same problem, but `ksh` works as expected).
Is there any way to workaround this behavior, and have Bash add the "inherited" child to its internal structures?

Comment: I'm guessing your real world requirement is a bit more involved than this sample otherwise you could pull the `wait` out to the parent script and have the `exec bash...` run after the `wait` has completed, eg: `wait ${pid} && exec bash -c 'echo This shell is $$; sleep inf'` ("Duh, Mark!" ?)

Comment: Indeed, my parent job performs an environment setup that is much better suited for C than shell. I only want to exec shell at the very end, because it's smaller. I could write another C binary for that purpose, but I hoped shell would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce it, but I wrote [a script](https://gist.github.com/lucaslugao/c7981fb921e0e2839e04d8317f9fafcf) that shows that this behaviour is consistent in at least 6 well maintained shells (including the mentioned ksh).

As you can see in the report, all shells won't list the first sleep job in the replaced shell, only the new one created after the exec call.

When invoking exec the new shell does not inherit the job list managed by the replaced one. It seems an intended behaviour but I could not find it anywhere in the POSIX specification.